# QtCreator не создает файл .exe

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qtcreator

Установил Qt Creator 4.0.3.

0) Настроил комплект "сборка и запуск":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1) Создал проект "консольное приложение".

2) Добавил код с выводом сообщения в консоль.

3) Собрал проект.

4) Запустил.

Получаю ошибку:

> Программа C:\fullpath\console1.exe отсутствует.

Т.е. exe'шник не создается..

Как исправить данную проблему?

Comment: А что компилятор с линкером говорят? Наверное, ошибки какие-то?

Comment: В консоли сборки никаких ошибок не возникает. 
При запуске, консоль запуска выдает соответствующее сообщение об ошибке, которое я указал выше. Если есть дополнительные возможности отображения информации на этапах компиляции и линковки то пжл скажите о них

Comment: А вообще какой-то вывод в консоли сборки есть? Приведите.

Comment: @Voidificator, `14:52:56: Прошло времени: 00:00.`

Comment: `set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "C:\fullpath\")` ?

Comment: У вас сборка вообще не происходит. В вашем скриншоте я вижу проблемы с комплектами сборки (красные восклицательные знаки). В частности, в комплекте 1 компилятор MinGW, а профиль Qt для VS. Может еще что-то не то. Как то криво это все установилось.

Comment: @Voidificator, действительно причина была в комплекте. Можете переформулировать ваш комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас сборка вообще не происходит. В вашем скриншоте я вижу проблемы с комплектами сборки (красные восклицательные знаки). В частности, в комплекте 1 компилятор MinGW, а профиль Qt для VS. Может еще что-то не то. Как то криво это все установилось.